# Google cloud run crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

I tried out google cloud run and working perfectly but suddenly got error while depolying after few days **crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'**

Everything seems fine, I have set project name, region but getting the same error

The command used is

> gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/cloud-run-test/image-name
>   --allow-unauthenticated --update-env-vars environment="PRODUCTION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, the google cloud run is in beta so the commands using to deploy may change in future.

What I did is updated the gcloud

```
gcloud components update
```

then after the update they introduced an additional parameter to specify platform.

The updated CLI code is

> gcloud beta run deploy **--platform managed** --image gcr.io/cloud-run-test/image-name
>   --allow-unauthenticated --update-env-vars environment="PRODUCTION"

You can specify platform as managed or gke

Available platforms:

- gke: Cloud Run on Google Kubernetes Engine. Use with the `--cluster` and `--cluster-location` flags or set the [run/cluster] and [run/cluster_location] properties to specify a cluster in a given zone.
- managed: Fully managed version of Cloud Run. Use with the `--region` flag or set the [run/region] property to specify a Cloud Run region.